# How to check if there is not request.referer in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http

I print some countries watching from what URL comes using request.referer. But if I refresh the page without any URL referer I always get the error bad argument (expected URI object or URI string).

Here is the code:

```
class CountriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    case URI(request.referer).path
      when '/artists'
        @countries = Country.select("countries.*, count(users.id) as artist_count")
                     .where("users.type = 'Artist')
                     .order("countries.name")
                     .joins("left outer join users on users.country_id = countries.id")
                     .group("countries.id")
     when '/galleries'
      @countries = Country.select("countries.*, count(users.id) as gallery_count")
                      .where("users.type = 'Gallery'")
                      .order("countries.name")
                      .joins("left outer join users on users.country_id = countries.id")
                      .group("countries.id")
    else
      @countries = Country.select("countries.*, count(users.id) as artist_count")
                     .where("users.type = 'Artist'")
                     .order("countries.name")
                     .joins("left outer join users on users.country_id = countries.id")
                     .group("countries.id")
    end                                    
  end

end
```

I want to put a 'if' before the 'case' but I dont know to check if request.referer is empty.

RESOLVED.

if request.referer != nil works fine but my problem was in the view that I use also URI(request.referer).path. I thought was in the controller.

Comment: also you were missing a closing quotation on line 6 of your code

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of the line you have:

```
unless request.referer
  #handle your case where no referrer
else
  # the rest of the code you have which depends on referrer 
end
```

But according to your logic, you don't need any switch statement:

```
class CountriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    #default to artists if no referer and use singluer form
    path = (request.referer || 'artist').gsub('/','').singularize

    @countries = Country.select("countries.*, count(users.id) as #{path}_count")
                   .where("users.type = '#{path.capitlzlize}'")
                   .order("countries.name")
                   .joins("left outer join users on users.country_id = countries.id")
                   .group("countries.id")
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks lacostenycoder! but I find the problem. The problem is not in this page ( controller ) is in the view that I use request.referer. if request.referer != nil works fine here

Comment: see updated answer, you don't need switch statement at all.  Dry your code up!

Comment: That is not the real code. The URL is more complex with more '/' and more paths. I just resume to focus in the problem